# How do i logout from yahoo chat in ubuntu?

Tags: empathy

In the top main bar next to battery, wireless, clock is an envelope icon where (I do not remember how happened) I am logged in to yahoo chat.
Say I want to login with another account or simply logout and erase user and pass people who might use my computer can not chat from my account by simply logging in back just by pressing a button.

So, how do I logout for good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1.** Choose `Edit` --> `Account` or Press <kbd>F4</kbd>.

**Step 2.** To erase user and pass uncheck `Remember password` and click on `clean` button.